# Chrome freezes when I use Adobe Creative Cloud

Tags: google-chrome, adobe-creative-cloud

I am on Windows 8.1. Chrome works fine for me until I open an Adobe product, then Chrome is completely locked up. This started happening for me a couple of months ago. I am wondering if this is a known issue.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Google: "Chrome freezes when I run photoshop" - that is the extent of it.  No results on front page.

Comment: Freezes how, totally unresponsive? Are there any errors in the logs? What version of Chrome? What plugins have you got installed? Please [edit] your question with this information.